# Windows 7 Machines Reboot Overnight (Intermittently)

Tags: windows-7, reboot

I have two Windows 7 machines, both with Windows Update set to "ask me before downloading or installing." Occasionally (about twice in two months so far), the machines seem to reboot themselves when I'm not around. This happened both times overnight. (Both are on a corporate network.)

What I would like to do is somehow determine the reason, and/or time of the reboot. For example, I can see that Windows Update did not install anything since November, so I know that it can't be that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You sure this isn't a coperate policy?  The fact its only happen twice tells me these restarts are from the patch tuesday that happens, once a month.

Comment: Look into the system event log.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm quite sure it's not a corporate policy. Nobody else in the office experienced reboots at this time.

Comment: @ZippyV what am I looking for? No reboots or errors reported; I have continuity of event logging across both days.

Comment: There should be obvious entries surrounding the reboots (at least of services starting afterwards). Check what the last few entries before the shutdown were, unless you have a hardware malfunction there should be clues to what initiated the shutdown. Either way, there usually is a message about a core dump somewhere.

Comment: Are they on UPS's?

Comment: Like Zippy and Eroen mentioned, look in Event Log (filter it) for the 'Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 6.01. 7601 Service Pack 1 Multiprocessor Free.' listing. Your versions may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot and other activity may be logged in the [Windows Event Viewer](http://help.artaro.eu/index.php/windows-7/essential-windows-7-administration/event-viewer-in-windows-7.html) under "Windows Logs" also check Custom Views > Administrative events for serious issues.

Comment: It does mention an unexpected shutdown/reboot -- no cause given.

Comment: It looks like a power outage due to a faulty UPS unit. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be Windows restarting itself after a hardware error.

Check Control Panel -> System and Security -> Action Center, and then under "Check for solutions to unreported problems," click on "View problems to report."  You might see some entries there.

Now, under Control Panel -> System and Security -> System, look on the left hand side and check "Advanced system settings."  Under "Avanced" go to "Startup and Recovery."  Click "Settings," and make sure that under "System Failure," the option "Automatically restart" is unchecked.